# exporting function in dll

Tags: c, dll

I have made a dll and exported the functions inside it using 
`_declspec(dllexport)` at the extreme left of the function definition. 
like :

```
_declspec(dllexport) void func1(char*p);
```

Is this correct method to export functions as somewhere?

I have read about `_stdcall` like:

```
_declspec(dllexport) void _stdcall func1(char*p);
```

or

```
_declspec(dllexport) void _cdecl func1(char*p);
```

Please explain the difference between these three as I am confused .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your declaration are correct. The important thing is that you provide a appropriate header file for the calling module that uses your DLL. e.g. one of

```
_declspec(dllimport) void func1(char*p);
_declspec(dllimport) void _stdcall func1(char*p);
```

or

```
_declspec(dllimport) void _cdecl func1(char*p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first signature is correct. So are the second and third. However, `_stdcall` and `_cdecl` are calling conventions which specify the ordering of parameters in callstack and some other things while the call is made. For example, '_thiscall' is another calling convention which means that the `this` pointer will be passed via a register(ECX) during function calling.

So, in short all three will work but all three specify some internal details of how call would be made.

You might need to read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to know more about Calling Conventions: